# The server tag is not well formed asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm doing the following query, and trying to use a code that come from a previous query.
But is giving me the following error: The server tag is not well formed.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TesteConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Equipa] where idAssemb=1 and idDept=<%# Eval("idDept") %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm using C# in Web forms asp.net

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Form where `idDept` parameter is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eval` is used in *DataBound* controls to evaluate a field value in a row from the data source. You are trying to use it inside a Data Source control itself (SQLDataSource in this case). You should use `parameterized query` by specifying the value of parameter inside `SelectParameters` tag like this:-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TesteConnectionString %>" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Equipa] where idAssemb=1 AND idDept=@DeptId>
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblDeptId" Name="DeptId" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Please note, here I have shown the example of a control present inside your WebForm. You can specify where the value of `DeptId` is coming from via Cookie, QueryString, Form, Session etc.

Comment: @CarlosSantos - You're Welcome. You can accept the answer if it helped you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work